# how to parse traffic data on google maps to json?

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I have a task from my campus. I have to make an app on android that can give us the best way from our position to our destination. I have made a map on android but it only contain distance. I have to add traffic data on my app. so I can use the traffic data to choose the best way in my map. but I have no idea to parse traffic data to json. is there any solution? please

Comment: Check "GET DRIVING DIRECTIONS FROM A TO B" out this one https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/

Comment: AFAIU your question seems to be about how to get traffic data api & not regarding parsing issue

Comment: Try some other sources as well https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/traffic-api/incidents/get/